# Keep example number together with floating table

Tags: floats, numbering, page-breaking, linguistics, linguex

I am using the package `linguex` (for 'linguistic examples') to number the examples in my text, using its command `\ex.`

I am creating a table that I am numbering with this command `\ex.`:

```
\ex. \label{my_table}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l l l l}
Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4\\
etc.
\end{tabular}
```

The option `[t]` for `\begin{tabular}` is necessary to have the example number be on the same line as the first row in the table.

My table is rather large, so I want to make it a float, so I embed the section above within a `{table}` environment. When I do this, however, the example number for my table is separated from the table, i.e. there is a page break between them. How can I prevent this?

```
\ex. \label{my_table}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l l l l}
Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4\\
etc.
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Hi. It's preferable to post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem rather than code snippets like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't put an `ex.` into a floating environment, but you can simulate it by manually adding the example number inside the `table` environment.  Depending on where the table floats to it's possible that the numbering might be out of order, but try it and see.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\ex. The first example.

\begin{table}[hbt]
\refstepcounter{ExNo}\theExNo\hspace{\Exlabelsep}\label{table}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l l l l}
Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4\\
Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4\\
Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
Some more text. This is a reference to example \ref{table}.
\ex. Another example.

\end{document}
\end{tabular}
```

**Update**

Note that the placement of the `\label` command matters with respect to subsequent reference to it via the `\ref` command.  If the label is placed immediately after the table, it will refer to the table counter, which is not what you want. If you place it after the stepping and displaying of the `ExNo` counter, it will behave as a reference to the example number, which is what you want.

[image: output of code]

Comment: What does the option [hbt] after {table} do?

Comment: These are standard float placement options which can be added to any floating element. `h` means "approximately here", `t` means "top of page", and `b` means "bottom of page". See the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Tables) for more details.

Comment: @Sverre Based on the problem you raised with the label,  I've changed the solution slightly to accommodate it.